# How to change icon's color of selected tab bar item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, uitabbarcontroller

I tried to change icon's color with UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor but it works only with systemImage and doesn't highlight image, only text.

```
init() {
   UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .secondaryLabel 
}

TabView {
        FirstView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Home")
                Image("home")
            }
            
        CatalogView()
            .tabItem {
                
                Text("Categories")
                Image("catalog")
                    
            }
        
        CustomerProfileView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Profile")
                Image("profile")
            }
           
            
        ShoppingView()
            .tabItem {
                Text("Cart")
                Image("shoppingbasket")
            }  
    }
```

I also tried .accentColor but Xcode says it will be deprecated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70920597/7129318) answer your question?

Comment: @Yrb hi! I tried UITabBar.appearance().tintColor and UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor but it doesn't highlight icons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `foregroundColor` in this case.

```
Image("shoppingbasket")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .foregroundColor(Color(.secondaryLabel))
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it finally highlights icon too.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine.

```
init() {
   UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .secondaryLabel 
}
```

But you also need to set your asset as a template image in the asset catalog:

[image: Template Image selection in Xcode]

So no need to use .foregroundColor